# Using MySql ,Retrieving nested JSON from the Array of JSONs based on the where Condition like mail or employeeName from the nested JSON only

Tags: mysql, jpa, jdbc, mysql-json

I got a task to Retrieve the data from the nested JSON from the array of JSONs using the where Condition

```
[
    {
        "taskName": null,
        "endDate": null,
        "assignedTo": [
            {
                "mail": "xxxxxxx.com",
                "employeeName": "xyz xyz",
                "departmentName": "ttttt",
                "region": "aaaaa"
            },
            {
                "mail": "zzzz.com",
                "employeeName": "kklkk",
                "departmentName": "tyeeee",
                "region": "iiiii"
            }
        ],
        "assignedBy": null,
        "labels": null,
        "priority": null,
        "special": false,
        "reviewedBy": {
                "mail": "89ui.com",
                "employeeName": "aalkk",
                "departmentName": "opopee",
                "region": "iiiii"
            },
        "description": null
    }
]
```

about is the nested JSON on which I'm working and want to display task to only persons who are assignedTo or reviewedBy based on their mailId

I have tried

```
select * from taskmaster.tasks where json_extract(assigned_to,"$.mail")="xxxxxxx.com";
```

and this one

```
select * from taskmaster.tasks where json_extract(assigned_to,"$[*].*")="xxxxxxx.com";
```

I found its reference from the MySql documentations

I'm just expecting some solution which will be easiest to remember and understand and works well
also is there any spring JPA method to make it even simplier??

Also recently I found out that the below query may work but the issue it gives me as if I uses 0 it only compares the first inner json of each row but it won't compare the 2nd json of the same row until I replace 0 to 1 I want query to be dynamically working. Now what to do.....

```
Select * from tasks where json_extract(assigned_to,"$[0].mail")="xxxxxxx.com"
```

Comment: Use `JSON_TABLE()` to turn the array into rows of a table, then use normal `WHERE` conditions. It's not easy to do directly with JSON functions.

Comment: Now you know why it's a bad idea to use JSON columns. Normalize your tables and this will be (relatively) easy with JOIN.

Comment: I got it friend @Barmar but I'm a rookie and just followed my sir's words. So will please share me a few more techniques to deal  with json...?

Comment: Sorry, while I think it could be done with JSON_TABLE I'm not prepared to spend the time it will take to figure it all out.

Comment: @Barmar what you mean by figure it out please can you explain

Comment: I mean write the solution. It's not simple.

Comment: @Barmar i found ---> select * from tab_name where json_extract(json_col,"$[0].json_field_name")="field_value"  it works very fine with every row but issue is only with first json of each column only if I want to check for 2nd json again again I need to adjust --->>>  "$[1].json_field_name"

Comment: If that solves the problem, post it as an answer. If it doesn't, add it to the question.